# Rspec 3.1 current_url == http://test.host/venues v application == http://www.example.com/venues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

I am testing a rails application with rspec 3.1 with the following expectation:

```
expect(current_url).to eq venues_url
```

This results in the following failure:

```
Failure/Error: expect(current_url).to eq venues_url

       expected: "http://test.host/venues"
            got: "http://www.example.com/venues"
```

Why is there the difference between the expectation domain and where the application directs to?

The test passes if I use `expect(current_path).to eq venues_path`